# How to convert escaped characters?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to convert strings containing escaped characters to their normal form, the same way Python's lexical parser does:

```
>>> escaped_str = 'One \\\'example\\\''
>>> print(escaped_str)
One \'Example\'
>>> normal_str = normalize_str(escaped_str)
>>> print(normal_str)
One 'Example'
```

Of course the boring way will be to replace all known escaped characters one by one:
http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

How would you implement `normalize_str()` in the above code?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
>>> escaped_str = 'One \\\'example\\\''
>>> print escaped_str.encode('string_escape')
One \\\'example\\\'
>>> print escaped_str.decode('string_escape')
One 'example'
```

Several similar codecs are [available](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), such as rot13 and hex.

The above is Python 2.x, but – since you said (below, in a comment) that you're using Python 3.x – while it's circumlocutious to decode a Unicode string object, it's [still possible](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).  The codec has been renamed to "unicode_escape" too:

```
Python 3.3a0 (default:b6aafb20e5f5, Jul 29 2011, 05:34:11) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> escaped_str = "One \\\'example\\\'"
>>> import codecs
>>> print(codecs.getdecoder("unicode_escape")(escaped_str)[0])
One 'example'
```

Comment: One good turn deserves another :) I once found that I could elegantly solve a problem by writing my own string codec, FWIW.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work in Python 3. I get: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.

Comment: in python 3, `str` is `bytes` and `unicode` is `str`.  You probably need to first 'encode' into utf8 or ascii (to get the bytes) then decode from 'string_escape'

Comment: Does this work with \t tab? I couldn't get it to, nor did printing directly to a string buffer, or redirecting stdout to a buffer. The only thing that did it was expandtabs.

Answer (score 7):

SingleNegationElimination already mentioned this, but here is an example:

In Python 3:

```
>>>escaped_str = 'One \\\'example\\\''
>>>print(escaped_str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('unicode_escape'))
One 'example'
```

Comment: For SSIDs as obtained from `iw wlan0 scan`, this gave me encoding errors. Solved that with: `print(ssid.encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8'))` --- Thanks for setting me on the right track, Attaque!

Answer (score 6):

I assume the question is really:

> I have a string that is formatted as if it were a part of Python source code. How can I safely interpret it so that `\n` within the string is transformed into a newline, quotation marks are expected on either end, etc. ?

Try `ast.literal_eval`.

```
>>> import ast
>>> print ast.literal_eval(raw_input())
"hi, mom.\n This is a \"weird\" string, isn't it?"
hi, mom.
 This is a "weird" string, isn't it?
```

For comparison, going the other way:

```
>>> print repr(raw_input())
"hi, mom.\n This is a \"weird\" string, isn't it?"
'"hi, mom.\\n This is a \\"weird\\" string, isn\'t it?"'
```

Comment: literal_eval requires a valid string literal, including begin/end quotes.  Adding the quotes (the sample in the question doesn't have them) has several edge cases, depending on what type of input you want to accept.

Comment: @Fred very true; but I imagine that in most situations where this is really the problem you want to solve, the begin/end quotes are actually there, even if OP left them out of the example. :)

Comment: I'm not sure that really is the problem you'd always want to solve: I'd guess the string_escape codec (as in my answer) exists to fill the real need of transforming escapes without having a string literal.  (Pointing out literal_eval is still useful though; I'm the upvote. ;)

Comment: this fails with prefixed/suffixed space/tab characters since that makes it invalid in python

Comment: Well, yes; those weren't part of the specification. "a string that is formatted as if it were a part of Python source code", inherently, begins and ends with a matching pair of either `'` or `"`, not whitespace. If you want to handle that, though, it's trivial to `.strip()` off first.

Answer (score 0):

Unpaired backslashes are just artifacts of the representation and not actually stored internally. You could cause errors if trying to do this manually.

If your only interest is removing a backslash not preceded by an odd amount of backslashes, you could try a while loop:

```
escaped_str = 'One \\\'example\\\''
chars = []
i = 0
while i < len(escaped_str):
    if i == '\\':
        chars.append(escaped_str[i+1])
        i += 2
    else:
        chars.append(escaped_str[i])
        i += 1
fixed_str = ''.join(chars)
print fixed_str
```

Examine your variables afterwards and you'll see why what you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

...But on a side note I'm almost 100% certain "the same way Python's lexical parser" does it is not using a parser, so to speak. A parser is for grammars, which describe the way you fit words together.

You're thinking of lexical content verification maybe, which is often specified using **regular expressions**. Parsers are an altogether more challenging and powerful beast, and not something you want to mess around with for the purposes of linear string manipulation.

Comment: What the OP calls a "lexical parser" might more accurately be termed a **lexer**, which Python certainly does have. Fortunately, we don't have to re-invent it; it's reflected in some detail - see my answer.