# Want to convert escaped characters to the actual characters in a string containing unicode

Tags: python, string

So please view the following question:

[How to convert escaped characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867588/how-to-convert-escaped-characters)

I need a bit of an extension to this question as here is my problem.

I need to be able to handle unicode characters in the original string as well.

Using the method 'unicode_escape' i end up with twice a proper string, but then how do i convert it back to a utf-8 string object with the proper number of characters ?

example:

```
s='\\n\\t'
#correct-ish except i can't get the escaped characters to translate this way
b=s.encode()  # b'\\n\\t\xf0\x9f\x98\x92\xf0\x9f\x98\x92'
b.decode() # '\\n\\t'
```

the example says convert to ascii and then use .decode('unicode_escape')

This does not work in this example.

It strips all the unicode characters.  If you remove the ignore it complains about them not being in range.. and its like 'uh yeah, so convert them to two bytes and be done with it' but no. Course not.  So far as writing my own the issue is circular. I'd end up with a table that said '\u201', and "\u201". I suppose I could get creative and actually write code that finds the characters and extracts them and then runs dynamic code to return the character but that seems a tad... overkill.

A search isn't revealing anything.

What I want is something that will convert the above string from `'\\n\\t'` to `'\n\t'`

Also don't 'body-shame' my post. haha. got that moby ?

Comment: `s` is a Python Unicode string.  `b` is a UTF-8 encoded bytes string.  The UTF-8 encoding of the sad face emoji is F0 9F 98 92, which is exactly what you have.  I can't tell what you are complaining about here.

Comment: And, by the way, Neither `s` nor `b` contains a newline or a tab.  `s` contains 6 characters, including 2 backslashes.

Comment: Are you looking for `"\\n\\t".encode("raw_unicode_escape").decode("unicode_escape")`?

Comment: `What I want is something that will convert the above` Then use `.replace("\\n", \n").replace("\\t", "\t")`.

Comment: @TimRoberts well then maybe read the question.

Comment: @JonSG write the answer up and i'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 0):

The user that actually read the question.
JonSG, may his family thrive.

To translate the escaped characters and preserve the unicode characters @JonSG found the following method and it worked perfectly:

```
#has a mixture of unicode characters and escape strings, yes there is a real world reason for this
s="\\n\\t"

#encoding using the raw_unicode_escape codec
b = s.encode("raw_unicode_escape") #produces b'\\n\\t\\U0001f612\\U0001f612'

# above value seems to satisfy the latin1 requirement, unicode characters don't throw errords.
#following translates all the escape sequences to their characters
s=b.decode("unicode_escape")  #'\n\t'
```