# Make Pycharm use double quotation marks and not one in the console

Tags: python, json, pycharm

I am trying to figure out how to configure Pycharm to use " and not ' when printing to console.
I've checked it, and it doesn't matter what I am using in the code itself, even if it is:

```py
print({"Hello World": "Great!"})
```

It shows up like:

```
{'Hello World': 'Great!'}
```

and not

```
{"Hello World": "Great!"}
```

As desired, I need this because when I want to format a long dictionary and view it as a nice indented JSON (and not a long line), it doesn't work as it is not a valid JSON as it uses the single quotation mark.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why not do `print(json.dumps(mydict, indent=4))`?

Comment: Why not use `rep()`

Comment: @snakecharmerb That's a nice work-around, I like it. But it adds unnecessary code... viewing it in the console itself is weird and unintuitive, I like to copy it to Sublime or other programs...

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675295/5320906)

Comment: PyCharm's console is just a plugin wrapping your [standard interpreter console](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) so if Python's interactive console can't be configured to show double quotes instead of backticks the IDE isn't going to override that.